# Worklight : Can we create different version of desktopwebapp

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Is there any way in workight where we can create different version of desktopwebapp as we can do for other enviornment like Android, iOs to ignore risk.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "versioning" support for Mobile Web and Desktop Browser environments in MobileFirst Platform. The only workaround to this would be to create another app in your project and add to it the environment, then copy/paste the contents of the previous app and use that as another "version".